# Sending Email Takes Too Long

Tags: mimekit

For some reason the emails are taking around 8 seconds to send, and it makes the website feel like nothing is happening.

```
client.Send(message);
client.Disconnect(true);
```

I am wondering if SendAsync would fix the issue, but would the following code cause any issues in the future:

```
client.SendAsync(message);
client.Disconnect(true);
```

I feel like the client could attempt to disconnect before the email is fully sent since the program won't wait for SendAsync.

Is there a better way to do this? I couldn't find an example in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to `await` the SendAsync() or you could end up disconnecting before the message has been sent.

That said, asynchronous methods, depending on how your application is designed, could be the right solution to making your app not "hang".